# laravel mongodb jenssegers allowDiskUse true

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I use [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) by jenssegers. I want to query a huge amount of data with order by and this is my query :

```
$stores = \App\StoreTransaction::where('date_time','>',1489944515)
        ->orderBy('date_time', 'asc')->get();
```

But I got this error:

> Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes

I know I should add **allowDiskUse** true to my query but how can i add it to mongodb jenssegers package ?

Comment: it would be more feasible to create an index on `date_time`

Comment: I'm not sure that you want to get all the results into memory. You should be able to use a cursor to get N results paginated.

Comment: Try `$stores = \App\StoreTransaction::where('date_time','>',1489944515)
        ->orderBy('date_time', 'asc')->paginate(100)` to get 100 records per time into memory. I'm not sure but I hope that this is implemented lazily. Otherwise, you want to do this using the cursor from a raw database command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Please do not modify vendor files

In your case, use the "options" method to allow disk use:

```
$stores = \App\StoreTransaction::where('date_time','>',1489944515)        
->orderBy('date_time', 'asc')
->options(['allowDiskUse' => true])
->get();
```

Comment: Hoa can we done this when using aggregate query?

Answer (score -1):

Goto "vendor/mongodb/mognodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php"
Goto "line 133"

replace **'allowDiskUse' => false**, per **'allowDiskUse' => true**.

Comment: Editting vendor code is not a good suggestion. As it's easy to lose sight where the changes were made and can cause weird and hard to find bugs.